# Convert UIElement to DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate, datagridtemplatecolumn, uielement

I have a `DataTemplate` defined in XAML. I want to customize it and give it to `DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate`. But when I call `LoadContent()`, the `VisualTree` is still null, instead a `UIElement` tree is returned. After I customize the tree, how can I convert it back to a `DataTemplate`? Or is there a way to feed the `DataGrid` cells directly with `UIElement`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've learned that once the UI controls are instantiated, it is impossible to convert back to a `DataTemplate` i.e. `FrameworkElementFactory` tree.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should help you

[Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43525/WPF-DataGrid-Using-DataTemplates-for-auto-generate)